# Merge a Git commit into another repository with different directory

Tags: git

We have two Git repositories "installer" and "software" with both containing an Apache Tomcat server:

```
installer/common/tomcat
software/dist/tomcat
```

I update Tomcat in "installer" and commit the changes.

When we used SVN I just used to do an `svn merge --accept=tf src@rev1 src@rev2 .` where `src` is the URL of the "installer" repo including `common/tomcat` path and `rev1` and `rev2` are the revision just before and after the update. The `.` is the `dist/tomcat` directory from "software".

The changes affect mostly text files and *.jar files.

I've been trying all day long to do the equivalent with Git and so far I think, creating a patch from "installer" about that single commit and applying it to "software" is the appropriate way, e.g.

```
/installer$ git format-patch --binary -1 <commit>
/software$ git am -p2 --directory='dist' <patch file>
```

I use -p2 to strip leading directories (which is 'a/common') and add the proper target directory from "software". I tried with "git diff" and "git apply" but only with varying error messages. Sometimes there are issues with text files and changes are not applied. Sometimes Git complains about the JAR files:

```
error: patch not applied to <file> which does not match the current contents
```

How can I achieve this and make Git stop complaining and just apply the patch? Isn't there a parameter like `--accept=tf` like in SVN?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are carrying the changes over a patch file.... that won't fly too high if files do not have the same paths. You should try to relate the two branches so that you could cherry-pick the change... that might be the way to pull it off.

Comment: Alternatively, another way to pull it off would be if you create a different branch in installer, say `tomcat`, rename `common/tomcat` to `dist/tomcat` there. Then when you want to bring over a change to `software` you first checkout `tomcat`, cherry-pick the revision there, then you can create the patch and then you should be able to apply it on top of software. It should be much simpler it you relate both branches (installer/software), for sure.

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks. The method with an additonal branch and renaming that folder worked. If you write it up as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: I'm glad. Done!

Answer (score 0):

One way to carry it out is through using a different branch, say `tomcat`, created from `installer`. In `tomcat` rename `common/tomcat` to `dist/tomcat`there. When you want to bring over a change from `installer` to `software`, you first cherry-pick it into `tomcat` (git should be able to see the renamed files and adjust paths accordingly) and then you can create the patch from there which should work fine in `software`.

Comment: While this worked once it no longer does. The cherry-pick of that change into the tomcat branch no longer detects the renamed paths and will not adjust them.

Comment: Try the renaming trick again on a *newer* (therefore sexier) tomcat branch. Perhaps files have changed so much that git is not able to figure out where the change is coming from.... actually, this leads to a different question: are you cherry-picking *only* the changes that you want to move? Because that explains why the files have _changed_ so much that git can't figure it out.